# Libgdx create polygon around an arc section of a circle for collision

Tags: android, libgdx, polygon, geometry

Here is the image of the graphic I am trying to create a polygon around:

[image]

This image will be rotating in a circle, and I want to create a polygon around it at the same rotation so that I can detect if another body overlaps it. I am using libgdx in android studio. I managed to do this in xcode using spritekit by creating a path reference and assigning it the physicsbody of the spritenode with the graphic above.

`CGMutablePathRef circle1Path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddArc(circle1Path, NULL, 0, 0, 135, 4.5*M_PI/19, 14.5*M_PI/19, NO);

circle1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:circle1Path];`

Comment: is this what you looking for https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

Comment: thanks, but I don't see how that would apply to a curved image like the graphics above. @Lakhan